# Ant System (pheromone trail)

Tags: javascript

How do I implement this in JavaScript? Thank you.

Ant System (AS) was the first ACO algorithm to be proposed in the literature (Dorigo et al. 1991, Dorigo et al. 1996). Its main characteristic is that the pheromone values are updated by *all* of the ants that have completed the tour. Solution components *c_{i,j}* are the edges of the graph, the pheromone update for *\tau_{i,j}*, that is, for the pheromone associated to the edge joining the cities *i*, and *j*, is performed as follows:

```
\tau_{i,j} <- (1-\rho)*\tau_{i,j} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \Delta\tau_{i,j}^{k}
```

Where the evaporation rate *rho* is in the interval (0,1], *m* is the number of ants, and *\Delta*\tau_{i,j}^{k}* is the quantity of pheromone laid on the the edge *(i,j)* by the *k*-th ant. If an ant uses an edge on its tour, the quantity of pheromone laid on that edge is calculated as follows,

```
\Delta\tau_{i,j}^{k} = 1/L_{k}
```

Where *L_{k}* is the tour length of the *k-th* ant. If an ant does not use the edge *(i,j)*, then *\Delta\tau_{i,j}^{k}* is zero.

[image]

I'm trying....

```js
 pher[i][j]= pher[i][j] *(1.0-rho) + numAnts*(.......
```

Comment: Looks like you are on the right path. What's the issue?

Comment: I dont know to continue its. I dont know to translate Sigma emblem, k=1

Comment: That's just a sum from k = 1 to k = m over the right hand part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a sum example. But I don't understand the rest of the algorithm. Do you have any pheromone matrix for example?

```
function sumk2m(k0,m,f){
    var result = 0;
    for(var k = k0; k<m ; k++){
        result = result+f(k);
    }
    return result
}

function isedgeintour(k){
    //I don't know what's this!
}

function L(k){
    //I don't know what's this either!
}

var deltapher = function (k){
    if(isedgeintour(k)){
        return 1/L(k);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

pher[i][j]= pher[i][j] *(1.0-rho) + sumk2m(1,numAnts,deltapher)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: The question fails the verifiable criteria, as is, since there is no expected behaviour associated with it. Other than this, I think it meets the others. This a common algorithm problem - the Ant System.